# gapless identity column strategy

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have experienced many problems at the hands of the identity column and I don't want to use it anymore. I want a different strategy. Ultimately, I want a gapless column of integers that are sequentially incremented on each row insert. I'm not sure how to achieve this. Is it possible to draw from a table that houses a sequence of integers or a function which creates them on the fly? Thank you for helping me with this technical problem.

Comment: Please share what you have done so far. Show us some code only verbose question doesn't help to understand actual problem.

Comment: @Jeet I think the question is clear enough. The question for what purposes he needs this strategy is rather interesting.

Comment: @RaulSebastian Agree

Comment: 6 altered the tables to change the new fields to not null
7 dropped the foreign keys and primary keys
8 dropped the old id fields
9 sp_rename the new fields to the old names
10 recreated the primary keys and foreign keys

Comment: The only part that i couldn't do programmatically was reordering the fields, which I did in Designer in SSMS. Going forward, I will use sequences in my databases. I'm fairly happy with the solution.

Comment: I thank everyone for helping, and especially those that treated this is a how and not a why.

Answer (score 8):

Why do you want a gapless sequence of values?

The reason why SQL Server -- and databases in general -- do not easily support this functionality is because it is hard to do.  Essentially, you have to lock the entire table for inserts, slowing everything down.

In general, it is sufficient to have an `identity` primary key.  Although you will get gaps, you can easily calculate a sequence using:

```
select row_number() over (order by <pkid>)
```

where `<pkid>` is the identity, primary key column.

If you do insist on gaplessness, then you will need to implement a trigger and do the calculation yourself.  I think a sequence (with no caching) will suffice for the production of the next number.  You do need to be very careful, though, about failed inserts.

Comment: Exactly. If for querying reasons you would want to get precedent or the next row consider LEAD and LAG windowed functions in sql server 2012+ Other than that, you can pack Gordon's statement in a computed column.

Comment: Sequence won't do any good. Once you have retrieved a value, the sequence is being incremented and then if your insert operation fails you have lost the value, creating a gap on the next insert.

Answer (score 1):

The gaps are a purely logical issue.

Assuming an insert operation can fail (and it can),
any 2 concurrent insert operations can lead to a gap, e.g. -

Last used value is 13.

Insert operation from session 1 uses 14.
Insert operation from session 2 uses 15.
Insert operation from session 1 fails (rollback).
Insert operation from session 2 succeeds (commit).

There is a gap between 13 and 15.

Since this is a logical issue, **you can't bypass it with a code, you will still need to serielize the insert operations**.
The only thing you can achieve with your own code is not having a gap if a serialized operation fail.

Comment: This is partially correct. You also get gaps when you delete rows. Alternatively to serialization you can implement a logic that reseeds the identity

Comment: No, fully correct, @RaulSebastian.1) I didn't talk about deletes because you have to initiate a delete, but failures you can't control. 2) reseed will close **an existing gap** and this will happen only when you'll have enough new rows.

Comment: Sql server implemens transactional sql follwing the  Consistency rule and your transaction either completely fails, but won't partially insert rows. Unless you mess up badly. So gaps mainly apear after deleting. As for reseeding you are absolutely right.

Comment: No @RaulSebastian, I am talking about 2 concurrent Insert operations, not a single transaction with 2 insert operations.

Comment: Right, I was thinking about single transaction containing a dataset or batch. In case of the concurrent transactions you would indeed create gaps. I don't see why he wants to avoid these

Comment: @RaulSebastian - maybe an SQL Server version that not fully supports windowing (e.g. `rows between 2 preceding and 3 following`) or a lack of analytics functions knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Gordon Linoff stated the core issue to your approach. Since it is not clear what you need your gapless Identity for, we can only guess. For querying purposes you should use the right statement. Consider ROWNUMBER() LEAD() and LAG(). If you need to query it often, you can pack the already suggested 
row_number() over (order by ID)
into a computed column named gaplessID for example. Other alternatives are:

- have a maintenance job that drops the index constraint, updates the ID column based on the ROWNUMBER and then readds the index
- implement the logic into your control layer and use identity insert
- use complex instead of triggers, which I don't  recommend due to bad performance

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments and answers thus far. In order to satisfy the philosophers out there, I'll explain why I want a gapless field. It's not based on any need, it's not a script that needs it, and this isn't a production application. I have a personal db in which I am lifelogging and sometimes the service goes down, I restart my computer, or any of the other reasons why the Identity gets gaps takes place. In one reference table, I have 47 records and the max identity is 2024. It's growing out of control on other tables.

Aside from future proofing, I am curious. When I see a problem like this for which there have been tons of posts, I want to find a work around or best practice. Since I asked the question, I've researched more and attempted to use sequences. After doing some experiments, I've decided that the performance is acceptable for my application. In order to switch over from identity fields to sequences, I enacted the following strategy:

1 duplicate db ( for testing purposes, I made all the changes on the dup ) 
2 create a sequence for each id field ( start with 1 increment by 1 no cache) 
3 alter tables to add new id fields ( because I cannot remove Identity property from a field) and add the default as NEXT VALUE FOR sequence 
4 updated the new id fields on each reference table with the NEXT VALUE FOR sequence 
5 for any tables that had a foreign key referencing one of the tables from step 4, i did a join on the old id fields and updated the foreign key field using the new field from the reference table
6 altered the tables to change the new fields to not null 
7 dropped the foreign keys and primary keys 
8 dropped the old id fields 
9 sp_rename the new fields to the old names 
10 recreated the primary keys and foreign keys

The only part that i couldn't do programmatically was reordering the fields, which I did in Designer in SSMS. Going forward, I will use sequences in my databases. I'm fairly happy with the solution.